# withAuthenticator signup complete

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my react native app, currently i'm using an AWS/Amplify withAuthenticator to make sure a user is signed up. The very first time a user signs up, i'd like to call a function once and once only, to create to store some user date elsewhere. Currently this code pulls up a standard AWS signup screen (i don't know where the code for it is hidden), where the user signs up:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, { includeGreetings: true});
```

The first time this user is successfully created in AWS, how can i find out its complete and then also call my own function? This function never need be called again.

Answer (score 0):

You should move that functionally into the aws lambads.

This [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html) describes how you can achieve that easily with the aws cognito dashboard. This enables you not only to set some state within a store from that lambda function, but you can also send them a mail or notify you that a new user singed up.

The other way, described [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#sign-up), is to write your own components to handle sign up. This also enables you to do something on user confirmation. This is a lot more complicated but it depends on your use case.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.